# Securing REST web service

Tags: security, rest

I have a REST api that I would like to secure so only my selected devices (which are embedded) can access the information. I don't want the users to have to login with their credentials; I just need the rest service to only be available for my specific set of devices.

How can I secure the WS to achieve this level of security?

Comment: See my answer for a similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006096/how-can-i-prevent-anyone-from-communicating-with-my-server-except-my-android-app/19008552#19008552

Comment: Can the embedded devices store X.509 certificates and do TLS authentication?

Comment: I do not know which embedded device you are talking about.  From X.509 certificates generate the public key in .der format and keep this file as resource.

Comment: They're android devices

Comment: It should be possible to .der file or a base64 encoded .der.b64 file in android.  How do you store images in android?  Even they are resources right?

Comment: Yes but probably a certificate would have to be stored differently than images.

Answer (score 0):

- Set up an X.509 certificate authority (CA).
- Issue certificates to your devices.
- Make your service only available with SSL and client certificates from your CA.

(This is not trivial.)

Comment: Will oAuth be of any use here?

Comment: OAuth is not relevant if you take the SSL approach. There may be alternatives based on OAuth; they're almost certainly vulnerable to security weaknesses (not OAuth itself, but any implementation). That may be okay depending on the level of security needed.